# Listing features in the order they were selected

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap, select

This is an ArcObjects-specific version of this question: [Create Array From Selected Features Based on the Order in Which They Were Selected](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27967/create-array-from-selected-features-based-on-the-order-in-which-they-were-select)

Is there a way to get the selected FIDs of a feature layer, selected with the interactive selection tools, *in the order that the features were selected*?

I've tried both enumerating and getting cursors over the map's FeatureSelection, the layer's IFeatureSelection.SelectionSet, and the IDisplayTable.DisplaySelectionSet. All returned in ascending order, not selection order.

I suppose that you could listen to feature selection events and track this yourself, but I was surprised to find out none of the above methods listed the features in selection order!

Comment: From all the documentation I've read, there doesn't seem to be any sort exposure of the selection order, though it would seem logical that some sort of array is created with additional features being added as they are selected.  Instead of doing this, then adding the FID as an included field in the array, they are simply creating the array and using the FID as the index for it, or that is what they are exposing.

Comment: sadly no option provided in ArcObjects unless you do some workarounds like listening to selection changed event as you said..

Comment: or maybe not..its possible!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reliably do it with an ArcGIS API. You have to listen to the Selection Events and keep track of it yourself. Sorry.

Comment: Cool, glad I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

**As other experienced users commented, the below method is only a workaround possible in Arcgis 9.3..This functionality is not documented and may not exist in other versions..**

The IEditor.EditSelection method can be used to retrieve objects in selected order to an enumerator. refer link below..

[IEditor.EditSelection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/EditSelection_Property/0020000000s8000000/)

The code below Worked for me in 9.3

```
IEditor sEditor = m_application.FindExtensionByName("ESRI Object Editor") as IEditor;
IEnumFeature enumFeature = sEditor.EditSelection;
enumFeature.Reset();

List<int> oidList = new List<int>();
IFeature selFeature = enumFeature.Next();
for (int fCount = 0; fCount < sEditor.SelectionCount; fCount++)
{
    oidList.Add(selFeature.OID);
    selFeature = enumFeature.Next();
}

List<string> strList = oidList.ConvertAll<string>(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,strList.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Nice one! Will have to try this. Sounds like this only works within an edit session though, correct?

Comment: @blah238 - sadly yes..but probably its useful only in edit sessions..

Comment: it is just an implementation side effect. You cannot rely on this functionality since this is nowhere in the API contract :-/ It *may* break across SPs

Comment: Doesn't work in 10.0 SP4 (returns in ascending order, not selection order) :(