# Script for populating field in ArcGIS 10 with consecutive numbers (where start numbers is decided by me)

Tags: python, vbscript, arcgis-10.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add automate values to attribute field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31706/how-to-add-automate-values-to-attribute-field)

I need a script (for Arc GIS 10) by which I can populate a field against some selected polygons features.
 For instance, i selected several polygons serially caring the plot number serial(for the polygon features) then i separated the selected polygons in the attribute tables.After all i want to apply  a field calculator to populate the field by consecutive numbers where the start number is as i wish, say 1283128.

Comment: Just a note, if the [order that the features are selected](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27980/listing-features-in-the-order-they-were-selected) is significant, you will need to use ArcObjects and create a custom selection tool or listen to selection events and maintain this information yourself. This is a much more significant amount of work compared to just using the script in the previously linked question.